# aws cli: upload a list of files from a text file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Hi using aws is possible to upload from a list of files?
for example I can upload one file at a time

```
aws s3 --follow-symlinks cp ./test.txt s3://<source>/test.txt
```

however what I like to do is to provide it with a file containing all the files to upload. Each file is in a different folder, hence why I can't just sync the entire folder

so say files_to_upload.txt should contain

```
file1 
file2
file3 
etc..
```

Instead of looping through each one is it possible to have it copy each of the files?
thanks.

Comment: Not without some kind of a loop.

Comment: The AWS CLI does not support a manifest file as input. Instead, you could write your own shell script or Python program to loop through the file and issue Copy commands. Or, sometimes I just put the list of filenames in an Excel spreadsheet and then make a formula that makes the full command and use Copy Down for every file. I then copy those commands and paste them into a command window. Works great!

Comment: you can use a script like that:
```while read p; do aws s3 cp "${p}" "s3://bucket-s3/${p}"; done <files_to_upload.txt```